# What does "char fun[](int x) const" do?: C++ Syntax Error

Tags: c++, syntax

I am [following along with a video emulating a cpu in C++](https://youtu.be/qJgsuQoy9bc?t=1280). The programmer used the following and it is the first time I encounter it:

This is the code from the video:

```
struct Mem
{
    Byte Data[MAX_MEM];

    Byte operator[]( u32 Offset ) // <-- I don't understand this syntax
    {
    }
}
```

I wrote it in my own project like this:

```
char data[1024*64];
char fun[] ( int x ) const  // <-- Is this right?
{
  return data[x];
}
```

my issue is with line `1#` of the example. They were able to compile but I am met with errors:

> incomplete type is not allowed;
> array of functions is not allowed;
> a type qualifier is not allowed on a nonmember function.

What does this syntax actually do; is there an alternative way to write it?

Comment: Please don't start lines of code with numbers. Instead, write a comment next to the lines you want to emphasize.

Comment: What compiler is this intended to be compiled with?

Comment: This is explained here a few times already (but I can't find it) ...

Comment: @tadman I am using the standard Visual Studio C++ compiler that defaults when using Desktop C++ Development

Comment: @TedLyngmo I tried my best searching before I posted. I'm still unable to come across something similar. Sorry for the repost if that is the case.

Comment: Is this **actual** C++, or just C? Just because VC and g++ can compile the majority of C code doesn't mean the code is valid C++.

Comment: Don't worry about it :) Ted is an expert, and is a regular on SO. If they're having difficulty finding a duplicate target, you are certainly not expected to have found one.

Comment: @Dai I am not 100% certain this is C++ but the project is made in VS and the code is a .cpp file. I am 99% sure it's C++ though. However I am still learning so I could be wrong. The references I used were using the same environment.

Comment: **The code in the video is nothing like the code you've posted**. `operator[]` is a special syntax in C++, it isn't semantically equivalent to `fun[]`.

Comment: @Maeximilian I've updated your question-posting to compare your code with the code from the video you linked.

Comment: @Dai the errors were just in the snip of the code. Also I simplified it for the question. However as Milo pointed out there are better ways of showing the minimal code. Again I am just curious of what the syntax does. Thanks for your input though.

Comment: @Dai thank you again for your input, I was unaware that operator[] is in fact fundamentally different from a function name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your minimal example isn't quite right; the syntax they are using in the video is very particular and you've changed some crucial pieces - they are overloading the indexing operator as a member of a class. A silly minimal example of what's going on is as follows:

```
struct X {
   char data[1024];
   char& operator[](int index) {
      return data[index];
   }
};
```

where you could later write code such as

```
X x;
x[5] = 'a';
```

where the snippet `x[5]` will invoke your user defined `operator[]` passing `5` as an argument. The important point here is that, essentially, the name of the function in the class is `operator[]` - and that that's just some special name related to C++'s feature of *operator overloading*. There's some fixed set of other operators that can be defined this way - you'll also see `operator()` is you want `x(a,b,c,...)` to be defined for an object of user-defined type `X` or `operator+` if you want `x+y` to be defined. Note that `operator` is a keyword - its name is not interchangeable with others. Also, for the indexing operator (and a few others), such functions may only be defined within classes (though some, such as `operator+` can be defined outside of classes).

There's a good general reference on overloading over at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading) question.